# Practical Considerations for a Square-Wave Inverter

Tags: digital-logic, inverter, switching

I'm hoping to understand some practical considerations for a square wave inverter.
Particularly, is there additional circuitry I need around the transistors to ensure proper operation? (e.g., switching glitches that short the rails, practical component variations that throw off the symmetric waveform, etc.)

Open to any other suggestions to, for example if there are more efficient topologies.

**Circuit Description**

The system is to transmit a +/- 1.5V square wave signal to downstream sensors over two wires.

The input voltage to the circuit is 5V, which is converted to +/- 1.5V rails.

Switching will be performed by a local FPGA by providing a +/-1.5V signal on the order of kHz.

The downstream sensors need more current than the FPGA pins can handle, so I thought to use the circuit below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcD4In.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Thanks for your time!

Comment: How much current compliance is required by the downstream sensors? I'm assuming your source is 0 to 5 V? What is its current compliance?

Comment: This circuit has many issues, and I don't see an easy way to fix it. You need to specify more requirements. Output voltage tolerance, output load, rise/fall time tolerance, etc.

Comment: Are you using all of the outputs of the FPGA or why aren't you just outputting an inverted signal from it as well? As a matter of fact, most FPGAs have selectable output standards including differential modes. For the higher drive strength, you'd then just need one inverter per output, and not one inverter and one buffer (which is typically two inverters)

Comment: What do you intend for D1 and D2 to do? As far as I can tell, once you've turned the FETs on they'll just make it impossible to turn them off....

Comment: @periblepsis The total load is 100 mA max.

Comment: @MarcusMüller So you mean just add an inverter at the output of the FPGA to increase the drive strength?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the load looks like, it is hard to know if this will work. But, I would be tempted to use an audio amp.

C2 and R3 are the values recommended by the manufacturer.

C3 needs to be really big if you want the square wave tops and bottoms to be flat.

A limitation of this design is that when it starts up, the output voltage will be higher than 1.5 V until C3 charges.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUb4Fv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>